# NoReverseMatch in Django url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

This configuration throws up an error, which is regarding the url call in index.html.

--index.html--

```
<td> 
    <a href="{% url 'manager:detail' a.name %}">
    <i style="font-size:120%" class="fa
          fa-clock-o"></i></a>
</td>
```

--views.py--

```
def detail(request, name):
    asset = get_object_or_404(Asset, pk=name)
    cals = Inspection.objects.filter(equipment__asset=asset)
    return render(request, 'manager/detail.html', {'asset': asset, 'cals': cals})


--urls.py--

url(r'^(?P<name>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

--Traceback--

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('TR-0000',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['manager/(?P<name>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` does not include hyphens, so `TR-0000` does not match.

You can change it to `[0-9a-zA-Z-]+`, or simplify it to `[-\w]+`.